# How to set time by location Android

Tags: android

I have a date in format (for example) "28-11-2014 00:00", and i want to show in android by location. I mean, automatcliy system check location and format for that location.

Example:

- London 28-11-2014 00:00
- New York 28-11-2014 19:00
- Paris 28-11-2014 01:00

In differente countries users will see different texts. Someone can help me?
Anyway, for testing that in emulator, what i can to do for change system locale?

thanks

Edit: I posted a solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
Most applications will use TimeZone.getDefault() 
which returns a TimeZone based on the time zone where the program is running.
```

With this you can get the Time Zone from which the App is running. Or do you want to display on your App Time zones all over the world?

You could then import them manually by checking the data on Internet or try googling for API's that include such things.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this with [Google TimeZone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/).

```
curl -X GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=39.6034810,-119.6822510&timestamp=1331161200&key=API_KEY

{
    "dstOffset" : 0.0,
    "rawOffset" : -28800.0,
    "status" : "OK",
    "timeZoneId" : "America/Los_Angeles",
    "timeZoneName" : "Pacific Standard Time"
}
```

You can get local time with following code.

```
TimeZone timeZone = new SimpleTimeZone((int) getRawOffset(), getTimeZoneId());
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeZone(timeZone);
String localDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm").format(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: First,thanks for your answer, but i have a time defined(example 19:00) and i want convert to system location.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't get it well. You have a time and your phone in London. then what do you want to see?

Comment: I want that people in Paris(for example), see other time. Like in example, if i show 19:00 in London, people in Paris will see 20:00. So format time by location

Comment: That's my answer describes. You get a location from the system and with latitude/longitude ask to google timezone api to know what timezone in that location. and you set timezone to that location's timezone and then you will see the time in that location's specific time.

Answer (score 1):

I got my own answer! Here is the solution

```
    //my format
    String format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"))
    //my date
    String dateInString = "2014-11-28 11:00";
    Date date = sdf.parse(dateInString);

    //my solution
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    System.out.format("%30s %s\n", format, sdf.format(date));
    //example
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));
    System.out.format("%30s %s\n", format, sdf.format(date));
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
    System.out.format("%30s %s\n", format, sdf.format(date));
```